# MVC Razor View: Output text as both raw and HTML parsed?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this...

I am essentially saving a huge blog post in a property called "Body" in a class called "Post".  In body I will have various things like

```
<p> Hello world </p>
<p> Some random paragraph </p>
<codeblock> Here is an example of a basic HTML page
<html>
<body>
<h1> Hello Guys ! </h1>
</body>
</html>
</codeblock>
```

Then I want to have a code block and thus I want the HTML/CSS/Javascript/etc to just be parsed to the page as HTML encoded/decoded so I literally want the tags and angle brackets to show up on the page instead of being parsed as whatever they are.

I also have a HTML tag called  which is ended by .  It's nothing special it just indents and adds some specific CSS with it.   I want the markup before the  and after the  tag to render the HTML tags as necessary.

Currently I am literally outputting the contents of the Body property using

```
@Html.Raw(post.Body)
```

Nothing special when I save it to the DB:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body)
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to show the raw version (which will let the browser parse the markup as html) with @Html.Raw(post.Body) and the version where its not parsed @Html.Display(post.Body) or @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Body) where the tags are escaped.

Comment: Correct @janhartmann

Comment: I want to post both the raw:  Html.Raw(post.Body) but somehow within that block I want to also parse portions just as @Html.Display....

Comment: I think I might just try Google's Prettify css/js files and see if that works better.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you use <pre></pre> in your markup?

Comment: Ah, I think I get what you mean. You need to escape the HTML when saving the content. And keep it unescaped and place it inside <pre></pre> blocks when display it on the page with .Raw();

Comment: Yeah I can use <pre></pre> in the comments.  I just did that using the prettify library on Google.  Thanks man, this got me going !

Comment: yeah @janhartmann .  I tested it out and it seems to work with non-markup languages just fine(C#, SQL, etc), but it completely fails with HTML or anything that has tags.  I need to find a way to just display it by having the code convert. 

I'm thinking of maybe doing the conversion myself on the backend.

Comment: After more research I figured it out.  You can use the <xmp> and </xmp> tag!

Comment: I just found out that <xmp> is depreciated.  I'm now lost again :) I guess i could always post it in a parser?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this? If so, can you post your source or git repo?

Comment: @JosephCasey sure see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for those that are still having this issue, this is how I resolved it.

1) I included prettyprint.  See link below

https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

2)  When editing a post I just add the following code
    
    //Bunch of code

Example:
    
    var http = require("http");

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
console.log(req.url);
resp.write("<html><body>" + req.url + "</html></body>");
resp.end();
});

server.listen(3000);

</pre>
```

In my Razor View I have the following code:

```
<div class="blog margin-bottom-40" onload="prettyPrint()">
//Bunch of other code up here for my view
    <div class="blogpost">
        @Html.Raw(post.Body)
    </div>
</div>
```

My blog is www.techiejs.com

Feel free to have a look and if you need another file from my solution let me know.  Currently my git repository is private.