# How do you sanitize and publish HTML into ASP.Net View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

## My Goal

**Save and post html to a blog post using C# ASP.Net MVC, using best practices**

How do I do this?

---

Below is the source that causes the following error:

> Error 2   Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'lambda
> expression'

---

## ArticleContent.CS (controller)

```
  // POST: Article/Articles/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,PublishDate,CreateDate,ModifyDate,Author,PageBody,Feature,Published,Excerpt,CreateDateUTC,PublishDateUTC,ModifyDateUTC,CanonicalUrl,UrlSlug,Category,Tag")] ArticleContent articles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Articles.Add(articles);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(articles);
    }
```

---

## Article.cs (Model)

```
    [Display(Name = "Body of Article")]
    public string PageBody { get; set; }
```

---

## index.cshtml (View) <-- Trigger

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((modelItem => modelItem.PageBody).ToString().Substring(0,250)))
```

---

## index.cshtml (Full Version of View)

```
<section class="bg-ocean row light text-center shelve">
        @if (User.IsInRole("canCreate"))
        {
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">
                @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
            </button>
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <article class="headline">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 headline-image np nm">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PostId })" target="_blank">
                                <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Feature)" />
                                <span>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Categories)
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 bg-light headline-content np nm">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PostId })" target="_blank">
                                <small class="dark">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifyDate)</small>
                                <h2 class="media-heading dark">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2>
                                <hr />
                                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Excerpt)</p>
                            </a>
                            <div class="headline-footer">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 172</span>
                                    <span class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PostId + "%23disqus_thread" })"></a></span>
                                    <span class="btn btn-default highlight" role="button"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> 210</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            @if (User.IsInRole("canEdit"))
                            {
                                @Html.ActionLink("E", "Edit", new { id = item.PostId })
                            }
                            @if (User.IsInRole("canDelete"))
                            {
                                @Html.ActionLink("D", "Delete", new { id = item.PostId })
                            }
            </article>
        }
</section>
```

---

## Questions as Resources

[How to save html to database and retrieve is properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662766/how-to-save-html-to-database-and-retrieve-it-properly)

[Text both raw and parsed html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535741/mvc-razor-view-output-text-as-both-raw-and-html-parsed)

---

### Future Note

Using  `.Substring(0,250)` with a null value creates an error due to strings 0 - 250 not existing.

Comment: What code triggers the error? I'm guessing it's the HtmlDecode stuff, but it's good if your post is specific.

Comment: The index.cshtml (view snipper) which reads: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((modelItem => modelItem.PageBody).ToString().Substring(0,250)))

Comment: shouldn't it just be `modelItem.PageBody.ToString()` not `(modelItem => modelItem.PageBody).ToString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a string and returns another. But you pass a lambda expression (`modelItem => modelItem.PageBody`) on that was the `ToString`- and `SubString` methods are called.

You must change your code to the following:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.PageBody).Substring(0,250))
```

In that code, you give the `PageBody` property to the `HtmlDecode` method and then call `SubString`. This string is given to the `Raw` method.

Much methods like `@Html.EditorFor` take a lambda as an argument, but `HtmlDecode` needs a string. That is the main problem.

PS: If `PageBody`is not a string, you must call `ToString`on it before passing it to `HtmlDecode`.

Comment: This doesn't work inside a foreach loop? Both item.PageBody and Model.PageBody are pulling up a NullReferenceException error.                       @ foreach (var item in Model{

Comment: Never mind. I found out the.substring(0,250) creates an error if the value for the PageBody string is null. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JosephCasey I suggest you check it with the `?:` Operator: `@(Model.PageBody == null ? string.Empty : Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.PageBody).Substring(0,250)))`

Comment: Html.Raw outputs IHtmlString so "? string.Empty" won't work. I'm checking for a way to check if IHTMLStrings are null.

Comment: Ok, I am not so familiar with MVC/Razor...but you can also change the Position of the `?:`: `@Html.Raw(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PageBody) ? string.Empty : HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.PageBody).Substring(0,250))`

Comment: That's the ticket. I also should note that I wrote it to pull the inner text instead since `<p>blah blah blah</` would be really bad.